# How do you vertically flip a figure in place?

Tags: graphics, rotating

I am using MiKTeX on Windows 7.

I am trying to vertically flip a figure that is a component of a multi-EPS figure.  The method I use is \scalebox as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}      % Specifies the document class
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{sistyle} 
\usepackage{rotate} 

\newcommand{\ip}[2]{(#1, #2)}
                         % Defines \ip{arg1}{arg2} to mean
                         % (arg1, arg2).

\input{psfig}

\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{0.8}%

\setlength{\textwidth}{7.0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.25in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-.25in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.0in}
\parskip 6pt

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centerline{
\scalebox{1}[-1]{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/OriginalObjects2.eps}}
\includegraphics[angle=90,width=2.5in]{c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/Samples/OriginalGravFieldHist.eps}}
\vspace{0.1in}
\centerline{(a) \hspace{3.5in} (b)}
\vspace{0.2in}
\centerline{\includegraphics[angle=90,width=2.5in]{c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/Samples/OriginalGravFieldHistDiff.eps}
    \includegraphics[width=2.5in]{c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/OriginalObjectsFiltSquared.eps}}
\vspace{0.1in}
\centerline{(c) \hspace{3.5in} (d)}
\vspace{0.2in}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/OriginalObjectsFiltCubed.eps}}
\vspace{0.1in}
\centerline{(e)}

\caption{whatever}
\label{whatever}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My problem is that it flips the figure around the bottom of the figure.  I would like it to flip around the middle of the figure so that there is no net translation.  How do I do that?

Comment: How about `\rotatebox{<angle>}{<content>}`?

Comment: Does \rotatebox flip or just rotate?  Thanks.

Comment: Well I suppose if you rotate it will eventually simulate a flip, right?

Comment: Not really.  If you flip a clock face around the horizontal axis, the 9 would still be on the left and the 3 on the right.  If you rotate it by 180 degrees, the 3 will be on the left and the 9 on the right.  The "angle=" effects rotation.  It's like turning a transparency over.  No amount of rotation will have the same effect.

Comment: True true. I take it back. Possibly a combination of `\reflectbox{<content>}` and `\rotatebox`

Comment: After `texdoc grfguide` I find: `\scalebox{1}[-1]{<your_figure_here>}` Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to reflect through the center. But see my answer to your previous question on almost this same MWE.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
ABC \reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{ABC}}
\end{document}
```

[image: flip]

Answer (score 10):

We want to use `tikz` for every thing ;-)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
ABC \tikz[baseline=(a.north)]\node[yscale=-1,inner sep=0,outer sep=0](a){ABC};

\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} \tikz[baseline=(a.north)]\node[yscale=-1,inner sep=0,outer sep=0](a){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you waiting for the omnipotent PSTricks solution? :-)

Comment: @DonutE.Knot Why not? ;-)

Comment: @DonutE.Knot Show us all. I love learning different ways.

Comment: Here is one at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312887/18678